# How to return all entity ids from google cloud datastore using node js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I want to list all the entities ids of kind of google cloud datastore in node js using google cloud datastore api

Comment: They have documentation to guide you through that: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-basic-query-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the entity ids with the following syntax if you are using nodeJS and gstore-node

```
var query = Model.query().filter("status","=",true).select('__key__');
var list = query.run();
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Its possible but you may end up exhausting your daily quota. You can retrieve up to 50,000 entities per day. If you need a higher quota you'll have to activate billing for your project and set a spending limit. See link below:

[Pricing and Quota | Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing)